# React Redux Datatable failed to initialise

Tags: reactjs, redux, datatable

I'm trying to using this package on my Redux React project. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-datatable ,

i have installed this package.

Like on their readme, I add reducer to my store:

```
import { DataTableReducer } from 'react-redux-datatable';
```

and i create some component for displaying table:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DataTable from 'react-redux-datatable';
import 'react-redux-datatable/dist/styles.css';


const apiLocation = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

const tableSettings = {
  tableID: 'BasicDataTable',
  keyField: 'request_id',
  tableColumns: [
    {
      title: 'Ref',
      key: 'request_id',
    },
    {
      title: 'First Name',
      key: 'first_name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Last Name',
      key: 'surname',
    },
    {
      title: 'Email Address',
      key: 'email',
    },
  ],
};


export default class userTable extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <DataTable
        tableSettings={tableSettings}
        apiLocation={apiLocation}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And when i go to browser my table rendering with no data and then show me error:

**The table failed to initialise. Please check you are connected to the internet and try again.**

I think here is something need to change in tableSettings but what i don't know exactly.

this key properties are what return from API? i tried to change them with what exactly return from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/user but i'm getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** the API response has to be in a [specific format](https://github.com/sean-ww/react-redux-datatable/blob/23464e0f34de05e5df6490b28134f05451c79fae/docs/get-started/get-started.md#example-api-success-2xx-response). It has to contain a key `searchSuccess` which is a boolean, `dataTotalSize` key to indicate the length of your array and `data` key to have the actual data array.

> Example API Success 2xx Response

```
{
  "searchSuccess": true,
  "dataTotalSize": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "ref_id":"5",
      "first_name":"Ted",
      "surname":"Corkscrew",
      "type":"Add"
    },
    {
      "ref_id":"26",
      "first_name":"Edwina",
      "surname":"Hosepipe",
      "type":"Add"
    }
  ]
}
```

Your Dummy API response has no `"searchSuccess": true,` key in it's response, that's why [FETCH_TABLE_DATA_REJECTED is distached](https://github.com/sean-ww/react-redux-datatable/blob/24c8709e0996a66841077713edc835862a47d992/src/DataTable.actions.jsx#L89). Also, beware, [it makes a POST request](https://github.com/sean-ww/react-redux-datatable/blob/24c8709e0996a66841077713edc835862a47d992/src/DataTable.actions.jsx#L44) to the API.

---

Your API response and `tableSettings` do not match.
Each key in `tableColumns` should correspond to a key in you JSON. And `keyField` should be an unique identifier for each object.

For example, an User in your JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
}
```

So the corresponding `tableSettings` would be:

```
const tableSettings = {
  tableID: 'BasicDataTable',
  keyField: 'id',
  tableColumns: [
    {
      title: 'ID',
      key: 'id',
    },
    {
      title: 'Name',
      key: 'name',
    },
    {
      title: 'Username',
      key: 'username',
    },
    {
      title: 'Email',
      key: 'email',
    }
  ],
};
```

I have only added 4 columns as an example, add more/less fields in `tableColumns` per your requirments.

Comment: Look into your console outputs and see if any error is thrown there?

Comment: No there is no have some errors, and on network tab i see that api call return success. But on redux tab reducer goes to FETCH_FAILED

Comment: I have found out what's wrong and updated my answer.

Comment: thanks i'll try it so i can't say jsonplaceholder to add this props to your api because i'm trying with dummy json file but i can't access to it, with api location = './data.json' console saying it's not found :/ i try to put data.json file in src, in component directory and in public directory already

Comment: Putting your data in client side (src or public) will not work because the library is making a POST request, you need to have server side code.  

Nevertheless this library is weird because nobody makes a POST request to **get** a bunch of data. I recommend you look for better alternatives.